# Iterating on group of columns in a dataframe from custom list - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **df** like this

```
TxnId     TxnDate           TxnCount
  100     2023-02-01      2
  500     2023-02-01      1
  400     2023-02-01      4
  100     2023-02-02      3
  500     2023-02-02      5
  100     2023-02-03      3
  500     2023-02-03      5
  400     2023-02-03      2
```

I have the following custom lists

```
datelist = [datetime.date(2023,02,03), datetime.date(2023,02,02)]
txnlist = [400,500]
```

I want to iterate the df as per below logic:

```
for every txn in txnlist:
     sum = 0
     for every date in datelist:
           sum += df[txn][date].TxnCount
```

I would also be interested to understand how to find average of TxnCount for filtered TxnIds.

After **Sum step** based on above input and filters:

```
 TxnId         TxnCount
  400          2
  500          10
```

Average corresponding to `TxnId 400 = (2+0)/2 = 1`

Average corresponding to `TxnId 500 = (5+5)/2 = 5`

If average > 3 , add row from dataframe to breachList

```
breachList =[[500,10]]
```

Please help me how to do this in pandas

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Comment: Added my expectation in the question @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter DataFrame by both lists first by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df['TxnId'].isin(txnlist) & pd.to_datetime(df['TxnDate']).dt.date.isin(datelist)]
print (df1)
   TxnId     TxnDate  TxnCount
4    500  2023-02-02         5
6    500  2023-02-03         5
7    400  2023-02-03         2
```

And then for sum of column `TxnCount` per groups:

```
out = df1.groupby('TxnId', as_index=False)['TxnCount'].sum()
print (out)
   TxnId  TxnCount
0    400         2
1    500        10
```

EDIT: If need filter `TxnId` by average, here greater like `4` use:

```
df1 = df[df['TxnId'].isin(txnlist) & pd.to_datetime(df['TxnDate']).dt.date.isin(datelist)]
print (df1)
   TxnId     TxnDate  TxnCount
4    500  2023-02-02         5
6    500  2023-02-03         5
7    400  2023-02-03         2

#create averages per TxnId
out = df1.groupby('TxnId')['TxnCount'].mean()
print (out)
TxnId
400    2
500    5
Name: TxnCount, dtype: int64

#get TxnId greater like 4
TxnId = out[out > 4].index
print (TxnId)
Int64Index([500], dtype='int64', name='TxnId')
```

Filter rows in `df` or `df1`:

```
df2 = df[df['TxnId'].isin(TxnId)]
print(df2)
   TxnId     TxnDate  TxnCount
1    500  2023-02-01         1
4    500  2023-02-02         5
6    500  2023-02-03         5
```

---

```
df3 = df1[df1['TxnId'].isin(TxnId)]
print(df3)
   TxnId     TxnDate  TxnCount
4    500  2023-02-02         5
6    500  2023-02-03         5
```

EDIT1:  For expected ouput use:

First filter by lists (for avoid processig all rows):

```
df1 = df[df['TxnId'].isin(txnlist) & pd.to_datetime(df['TxnDate']).dt.date.isin(datelist)]
print (df1)
   TxnId     TxnDate  TxnCount
4    500  2023-02-02         5
6    500  2023-02-03         5
7    400  2023-02-03         2
```

Pivoting for all combinations `TxnDate/TxnId` :

```
out = df1.pivot_table(index='TxnId', 
                      columns='TxnDate', 
                      values='TxnCount', 
                      aggfunc='sum', 
                      fill_value=0)
print (out)
TxnDate  2023-02-02  2023-02-03
TxnId                          
400               0           2
500               5           5
```

Last filtered summed values by means per rows and convert to lists:

```
breachList = out.sum(axis=1)[out.mean(axis=1).gt(3)].reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()
print (breachList)
[[500, 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very elegant. @jezrael
 Instead modifying the TxnCount column inplace, If i need to find the average of TxnCount for every TxnId in df1 and populate those rows matching to a condition lets say avg > 4 into a separate list/dataframe. How do we do that?

Comment: @KurinchiMalar - Do you think `df1.groupby('TxnId', as_index=False)['TxnCount'].mean()` ?

Comment: @KurinchiMalar - Yes, but problem is if mising some combinations, then it count only from `4` instead `0,4`. So need pivoting for `0` and then processing like in `EDIT1`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your are using a nested loop is reminiscent of a 2D [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) (or [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)):

```
df['TxnDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TxnDate'])

out = (df.pivot_table(index='TxnId', columns='TxnDate',
                      values='TxnCount', aggfunc='sum'
                      fill_value=0)
         .reindex(txnlist, datelist)
       )
```

Output:

```
TxnDate  2023-02-03  2023-02-02
TxnId                          
400               2           0
500               5           5
```

And if you want to further aggregate on Ids (or Date):

```
out.sum(axis=1)

TxnId
400     2
500    10
dtype: int64
```